# can't switch between pages in cPanel

Tags: reactjs, web, cpanel

I'm new to web-hosting and cPanel, so please be nice to me...
I have built a website using react and managed to upload its build file to cPanel. It seems to work fine, however, whenever I try to switch between pages, I get a 404 error, although the pages clearly exist (for example, when I press a button to switch to mydomainname.com/about-us). The switching works perfectly locally using react-router..
I would really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because ReactJS uses client side routing.

To fix 404, create a `.htaccess` file and paste below contents and upload it to your site root. It should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

If the above did not work, try below ([recommended by ReactJS team](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)), either one of this should work

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

> The switching works perfectly locally using react-router

Routing works fine with the inbuilt ReactJS web server but not with Apache web server. Also make sure you are using react router [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) component to navigate between pages and not the html anchor (`a`) tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect all the requests to your index.html. You can edit the `.htaccess` for that. use `<Link>` from react-router to make redirections.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps and you will be fine

Specify your homepage in your package.json file like this

```
{
  "name": "yourappname",
  "homepage": "http://example.com",//add your domain here line
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
 }
```

2.Build your app by running `yarn build` or `npm run build`

3.Then copy the contents of your build folder and paste them on public_html folder in your cpanel

3.Go to your Cpanel file manager public_html folder and edit .htaccess file or create new one if it does not exist. and paste this there

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

**Note** the .htaccess for this should be at the same level with the contents of the build folder.

Save and your are done